# Can we develop a control which is useful in windows as well as in Web application

Tags: c#-3.0

I want to develop a control which is useful in C# Windows as well as in ASP.net
So what is the way to create such control

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it easily, as WinForms and ASP.NET render their controls in totally different ways. The best you can do is to keep as much of the common code (i.e. properties etc) in a shared partial or base class<sup>1</sup>, and write a separate UI for each version.

<sup>1</sup>You can share the same class between two different projects by having the file physically in one project and then sharing it as a link with the other project. If you choose to use a base class approach then that base class can sit in a third UI independant assembly.